# Web Service query on Sharepoint 2007 List with 12,000 items fails to return all documents

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, large-data-volumes

We are querying a large SP 2007 document library with over 12,000 documents using the Lists web service, for document comparison purposes.
All queries are built using CAML, to limit the results returned by one of the fields on the list.
In general, the CAML query will return no more than 200 records.

Unfortunately, we are finding that one query will return 20 documents, and the exact same query will return 23 documents 15 minutes later.
As this crawl occurs after hours, it is not possible that documents have been added during that time.

Has anyone experienced similar issues ?

Comment: Can you post a code sample containing both the CAML query and the method in which you're invoking the query?

Comment: When you say as this crawl occurs, are you building the crawler? If so i'd ask for more information about the purpose because you'd be better off using the sharepoint search services and working against this instead of the list directly.

Comment: We are building the crawler.  Search services are not an option for the business logic that we are required to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was related to hardware errors on one of our front end web servers.
This caused a validation failure for some of the List Items.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586530%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method, try setting the RowLimit parameter to something larger.

> rowLimit   A string that specifies the number of items, or rows, to
>   display on a page before paging begins. If supplied, the value of this
>   parameter overrides the row limit set in the view specified by the
>   viewName parameter or the row limit set in the default view for the
>   list.

If you don't specify, it will use the limit for the default view which is probably 200 judging by your question.

I don't understand the second part of your question. The search index uses a completely separate web service and you'll never use CAML to query the search index.